# jsonsimple: Unhandled exception type ParseException

Tags: java, json-simple

I'm using Eclipse and I'm trying to follow along this tutorial:

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_2_-_Faster_way:_Reuse_instance_of_JSONParser

But I'm encountering some problems when using a JSONParser object. When I try to simply call:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(json_out);
```

I get an error saying: Unhandled exception of type ParseException.

But when I use a try statement I get:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{    
        Object obj = parser.parse(json_out);
    }catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


Unhandled exception type ParseException
Unreachable catch block for ParseException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: what's the type of `json_out`

Comment: It's just a JSON file as a string.

Comment: i meant the type of the variable `json_out` , is it Reader or InputStream?

Answer (score 0):

So according to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) the JSONParser class does not contain a parse() method.

You can use this as a possibility:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(content);
```

Then parse it using this:

```
JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
```

Comment: That is a different JSON library, so the JSONParser classes are different.